# sed: replace only the first range of numbers

Tags: regex, sed

Imagine I have an input file like this:

```
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('9', '29');
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('19', '312');
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('414', '1');
```

And I wish to add 10000 to only the first range of numbers, so I end up with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('10009', '29');
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('10019', '312');
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('10414', '1');
```

My approach would be to prefix "1000" to one digit numbers, "100" Something like...:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{2\}/10&/g'
```

... isn't very helpful, since it changes each occurance of two numbers, not only in the first occurance of numbers:

```
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('9', '10029');
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('10019', '100312');
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('100414', '1');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `awk` instead of `sed`:

```
awk -F"'" '{OFS="'"'"'"; $2=$2+10000; print}'
```

Comment: +1 this might be a bit more readable: `OFS="'\''"`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's an elegant way to do it with one command (and I don't think so), but you can easily do it with one command per length of numbers:

```
sed -e "s/'\([0-9]\{1\}\)',/\'1000\1\',/g"
sed -e "s/'\([0-9]\{2\}\)',/\'100\1\',/g"
sed -e "s/'\([0-9]\{3\}\)',/\'10\1\',/g"
```

The trick to change only the numbers you want is to include some context in the pattern, here the single quotes and the comma, so that your pattern is unique in your strings.

The result of each command is the following:

```
$ sed -e "s/'\([0-9]\{1\}\)',/\'1000\1\',/g" test
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('10009', '29');
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('19', '312');
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('414', '1');

$ sed -e "s/'\([0-9]\{2\}\)',/\'100\1\',/g" test
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('9', '29');
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('10019', '312');
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('414', '1');

$ sed -e "s/'\([0-9]\{3\}\)',/\'10\1\',/g" test
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('9', '29');
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('19', '312');
INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('10414', '1');
```

Comment: Call me stupid, but that brings me:

    INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('9', '10029');
    INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('10019', '100312');
    INSERT INTO video_item_theme VALUES('100414', '1');

Comment: maybe it was a syntax problem. I updated my answer and tested it, I have the results you wanted

Comment: Well feel free to validate the answer then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Same solution as *Ansgar Wiechers*, but in `perl`:

```
perl -F\' -lane '$F[1] += 10000; print join "\047", @F' infile
```

- `-a` auto-splits into `@F` at `'`.
- `-n` loops over each line.

See `perlrun(1)`.